# Telerik WinForm RadGridView Clear Filtering

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, filtering, radgridview

Please take a look at this link :
[how-to-clear-radgrid-filters](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/how-to-clear-radgrid-filters)
But this link is for asp.net, not WinForms.
In WinForms there is no `GridColumn` or `RadGrid1.MasterTableView`.
How can i clear filtering of telerik radgridview in winforms?

Comment: C'mon you've been around long enough to know link only questions are a BIG no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.radGridView1.FilterDescriptors.Clear();` as per https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-clear-the-built-in-filters.